# Angular post request sending empty body to node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http

I am trying to post form data from angular to node.js. The angular post request sends an empty body.
this is my post router
submit function is ts file

```
  onSubmit( loginData ) {
if(!loginData) { return; }
this.userService.addUser( loginData as User  )
  .subscribe(user => {
    this.users.push(user);
  });
```

service used to post data

```
   addUser(user: User): Observable<User> {
    // console.log('this is '+user.email);
    const url = `${this.usersUrl}/register`;
    return this.http.post<User>(url, user).pipe(
      tap((newUser: User) => this.log(`added user w/ email=${newUser.email}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<User>('addUser'))
    );
  }
```

Comment: how you are reading data in nodejs?

Comment: @MichaelD, I guess you misunderstood the question. He wants to send the data of user as body to make the entry in database or something so it is required to send the user object and not the empty string.

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser's debugger. Can you see the request's body?

Comment: Can you confirm that the user object is not null/undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
There is no problem in this angular code.
I also checked the network tab as suggested by David, and saw that the payload was being sent.
the problem was this line of code in my node.js server

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Instead I had to use

```
app.use(exrpess.json())
```

I had copied the template from another application and somehow missed this. Anyway thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check once by adding the debug whether the loginData is getting passed in the service or not.
If you don't know how to add debug point simply just print the data using `console.log(user)` 
in the method addUser() as the first line.

And if not getting data then simply modify the method call by:

```
this.userService.addUser(loginData).subscribe(user => {
  this.users.push(user);
    });
```